# No interface supported error for OPC

Tags: c#, interface, tcp, plc, opc

I have built a OPC client in c#. when i try to connect it gives me the following exception

> "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'OpcRcw.Comn.IOPCServerList2'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{9DD0B56C-AD9E-43EE-8305-487F3188BF7A}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE))."

I have installed the OPC Redistributable Package.

Let me know why this error is caused. Also i tried with a standard OPC client (softing OPC DA Demo client) and that seems to work well without any issues.. Why cannot i connect when i use the following code :

```
Opc.Da.Server server = new Opc.Da.Server(new OpcCom.Factory(), new Opc.URL(connectionString));                       
this.server.Connect();
```

Comment: If the OPC runtime is properly installed then this indicates that the OPC server only implements OPC v1.0.  IOPCServerlist2 is an OPC v1.1 interface.

Comment: By mentioning OPC Runtime did you mean the OPC Redistributable Package? . If so then i have installed them. But how do i solve this issue. Where do i get the compatible run time for this version?

Comment: I tried with the OPCAutomation namespace and it gave me an exception from the COM Component. the Interop binaries is raising this error. I have done all DCOM settings in the client computer